# Vasicek and Extended Vasicek Model

Tags: vasicek

I want to ask about basic reasoning in Vasicek and Extended Vasicek model.

1. Why $P(T,T) = 1$ for non arbitrage model? Can we place $P(T,T) = 10$ or other numbers? Is it correlated with The Law of Single Price?
2. How can you have an idea to write $P(t,T,r) = A e^{-Br}$ or $e^{A - Br}$. Why not other function?
3. What is actually market price of risk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In general, for $t<T$, $P(t, T)$ is the price at time $t$ of a $T$-maturity zero coupon bond with a principal of $1$. It is commonly called the discount factor between time $t$ and $T$, since it is the value at time $t$ of receiving $1$ unit at time $T$. Using this idea, for $t=T$, it is easy to see why $P(T, T)=1$. What is the value at time $T$ of receiving $1$ unit at time $T$? It is simply $1$! Of course, you can change your notation and let $P(t, T)$ denote a zero coupon bond with a principal of e.g. $10$, thereby changing your numeraire, which would result in the no-arbitrage condition $P(T, T) = 10$.
2. This was simply presented as a "guess" in the initial papers. This guess in turn seems to work out very nicely (in this model and other [affine term structure models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_term_structure_model)).
3. The market price of risk is extensively covered many places on [this site](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/33681/how-to-understand-the-market-price-of-risk) and [elsewhere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risk-neutral_measure).

Comment: Can I ask you another question? Why we bother to count the zero coupon bond price? Are there advantages of zero coupon bond over a normal bond with coupon mathematically?

Comment: This is exactly because of the discounting property described above. You can use the ZCB prices to discount other cash flows. Basically, if you have a coupon bearing bond that pays 5% annually on a \$100 principal for 3 years, you get \$5 a year for 3 years. This is equivalent to holding 5 ZCBs with maturity 1, 5 ZCBs with maturity 2, and 5 ZCBs with maturity 3. Hence, the coupon bearing bond price is simply the sum of its component ZCB prices.